# Making a cubic ease-in-out curve dynamically switch its goal position

Tags: lua, interpolation, cubic

Using, Lua, I've made a function to cubically (easing in/"accelerating", then easing out/"decelerating" afterwards) interpolate from one number to another; SimpleSpline takes a number between 0-1 (the time the animation's been going, easiest put), and SimpleSplineBetween does the same, but keeps it in between two given minimum/maximum values.

```
function SimpleSpline( v )
    local vSquared = v*v
    return (3 * vSquared - 2 * vSquared * v)
end

function SimpleSplineBetween( mins, maxs, v )
    local fraction = SimpleSpline( v )
    return (maxs * fraction + mins * (1 - fraction))
end
```

It all works fine. However, I've run into a bit of an issue. I'd like this to be a bit more *dynamic*. For example, assume my "mins" is 0.5, and my "maxs" is 1, then I have a variable for time that I pass as V; we'll say it's 0.5, so our current interpolation value is 0.75. Now, let's also assume that suddenly, "maxs" is jerked up to 0.25, so now, we have a new goal to reach.

My current approach to handling situations like the above is to reset our "time" variable and change "mins" to our current value; in the above case 0.75, etc. However, this produces a *very* noticable "stop" or "freeze" in the animation, because it is being entirely reset.

My question is, how can I make this dynamic without that stop? I'd like it to transition smoothly from moving to one goal number to another.

Comment: After "maxs" is jerked up to 0.25, is additional time introduced for achieving the new value of "max" from your current position?

Answer (score -1):

```
local Start_New_Spline, Calculate_Point_on_Spline, Recalculate_Old_Spline
do

   local current_spline_params

   local function Start_New_Spline(froms, tos)
      current_spline_params = {d=0, froms=froms, h=tos-froms, last_v=0}
   end

   local function Calculate_Point_on_Spline(v)  --  v = 0...1
      v = v < 0 and 0 or v > 1 and 1 or v
      local d     = current_spline_params.d
      local h     = current_spline_params.h
      local froms = current_spline_params.froms
      current_spline_params.last_v = v
      return (((d-2*h)*v+3*h-2*d)*v+d)*v+froms
   end

   local function Recalculate_Old_Spline(new_tos)
      local d     = current_spline_params.d
      local v     = current_spline_params.last_v
      local h     = current_spline_params.h
      local froms = current_spline_params.froms
      froms = (((d-2*h)*v+3*h-2*d)*v+d)*v+froms
      d = ((3*d-6*h)*v+6*h-4*d)*v+d
      current_spline_params = {d=d, froms=froms, h=new_tos-froms, last_v=0}
   end

end
```

Usage example according to your values:

```
Start_New_Spline(0.5, 1)      -- "mins" is 0.5, "maxs" is 1
local inside_spline = true
while inside_spline do
   local goal_has_changed = false
   for time = 0, 1, 0.015625 do  -- time = 0...1
      -- It's time to draw next frame
      goal_has_changed = set to true when goal is changed
      if goal_has_changed then
         -- time == 0.5 ->  s == 0.75, suddenly "maxs" is jerked up to 0.25
         Recalculate_Old_Spline(0.25)  -- 0.25 is the new goal
         -- after recalculation, "time" must be started again from zero
         break  -- exiting this loop
      end
      local s = Calculate_Point_on_Spline(time)  -- s = mins...maxs
      Draw_something_at_position(s)
      wait()
   end
   if not goal_has_changed then
      inside_spline = false
   end
end
```